# Issue in Apache Cassandra - io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException

Tags: database, docker, cassandra

Hi I'm getting the following error in my Cassandra instance hosted on a Docker.

```
WARN  [epollEventLoopGroup-5-4] 2023-10-22 00:46:51,808 PreV5Handlers.java:261 - Unknown exception in client networking
io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer
```

I'm not sure whether this is related to Cassandra or Docker.  I followed the below steps to fix the issue but had no luck.

1. Updated Docker and Cassandra to the latest versions.
2. Re-checked Docker and firewall configurations
3. Changed the docker network mode

Can you please help me with the issue?

Comment: Any idea what was the issue?